# Is there a way to force update query to set a column value in postgreSQL?

Tags: postgresql, triggers

I have a table with a column id_user_update that keeps the id of the user that inserted/updated the rows. I created a trigger that tests if this column is NULL and throw an exception. But this works only on INSERT queries, because in UPDATE queries, if this column is not set, the current value it's used. In other words, NEW.id_user_update becomes iqual to OLD.id_user_update, if it's not set in the query.

The only solution I found is to remove user permission to update and force him to use a function. But this is not an option in this case.

Any ideas?

Comment: Welcome to Stackoverflow! Please add your table create statement so that we can know if there is any constraint of column which is blocking the update.

Comment: The update is not beeing blocked. The thing is: when I update and do not set the id_user_update value, it kee´s the current value. What I want is to force this value to be set every time, even if it's the same as the current.

Answer (score 0):

You would simple define the trigger `ON INSERT OR UPDATE`:

```
CREATE FUNCTION mytrig() RETURNS trigger
   LANGUAGE plpgsql AS
'BEGIN
   NEW.id_user_update = get_current_user();
   RETURN NEW;
END;';

CREATE TRIGGER mytrig BEFORE INSERT OR UPDATE ON atable
   FOR EACH ROW EXECUTE PROCEDURE mytrig();
```

All that remains is to have a function or some other way to get the user ID of the current user.

Comment: Actually this id_user is not a DB user. That's an foreign key to another table.

Comment: That shouldn't make a difference. The `get_current_user` is something that you have to provide. Can you describe what value you would like to have in `id_user_update`?

Comment: It could be any other column, what I want is to consider an specific column null if it's not set in the update query, instead of using current value. Or, somehow, to verify if the column is set in the query.

Comment: I don't understand. Perhaps you should [edit] the question and show a more complete example of what you want.